# ¿Cómo buscar un elemento recursivamente?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Me gustaría hacer una recursividad en mi código para poder buscar un elemento en mi listbox y ver si este existe , en caso de que exista muestre un mensaje positivo y en caso de que no exista , muestre un mensaje negativo, he intentado varias cosas pero no me han funcionado.A continuación les dejare mi codigo para que lo revisen y puedan darme su opinión

private void CargarDatos()
{
try
{
#region "Nodos"
tree = new TreeView();
if(File.Exists("nodos.xml")) // Si existe el xml carga los archivos de este
{

```
                XmlDocument doc;
                doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load("nodos.xml");
                cargandoNodosXML(doc.DocumentElement, treeView1.Nodes);
                treeView1.ExpandAll();  // Para expandir todos los nodos del arbol.
                tree=treeView1;
            }
            #endregion

            #region"Elementos"

            ListaElemento = new List<Elemento>();
            //Cargamos el archivo de elementos y si existe lo Eliminamos

            lector = new StreamReader(File.Open("elementos.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate));
            //Vamos leyendo las lineas y  añadiendolas a la lista

            while((linea=lector.ReadLine())!=null)
            {
                string nodo, empleo;
                nodo = empleo = "";


                int pos=0, aux = -1;

                aux = linea.IndexOf("|", pos);
                //Nodo
                if(aux>-1)
                {
                    nodo = linea.Substring(pos, aux);
                    pos = aux + 1;
                    aux = -1;
                    linea = linea.Substring(pos);

                }
                //Elemento
                pos = 0;
                aux = linea.IndexOf("|", pos);
                if(aux>-1)
                {
                    empleo = linea.Substring(pos, aux);
                    pos = aux + 1;
                    aux = -1;
                    linea = linea.Substring(pos);
                }
                ListaElemento.Add(new Elemento(nodo, empleo));


            }
            lector.Close();
            #endregion



        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.Message+ "Error al cargar los datos"+MessageBoxButtons.OK+MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }

    private TreeNode creaNodo(XmlNode nodo)
    {
        try
        {

            TreeNode aux = new TreeNode();
            if(nodo.HasChildNodes && nodo.FirstChild.Value!=null)
            {
                aux = new TreeNode(nodo.Name);
                TreeNode nodo2 = new TreeNode(nodo.FirstChild.Value);
                aux.Nodes.Add(nodo2);
            }
            else if(nodo.NodeType!=XmlNodeType.CDATA)
            {
                aux = new TreeNode(nodo.Name);
            }
            return aux;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Source + "\n" + ex.Message, "crear Nodo", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return null;
        }
    }
    private TreeNodeCollection AddNode(XmlNode nodo, TreeNodeCollection padre)
    {

        try
        {
            TreeNode  nuevoHijo = creaNodo(nodo);
            // Si no hay nada que añadir devuelve al padre 
            if (nuevoHijo == null)
                return padre;
            // Añade el nuevo nodo al Padre
            if (padre != null)
                padre.Add(nuevoHijo);

            return nuevoHijo.Nodes;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Source + "\n" + ex.Message, "Error al Agregar Nodo", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return padre;
        }
    }

    private void cargandoNodosXML(XmlNode nodo, TreeNodeCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            if(nodo==null ||nodo.NodeType==XmlNodeType.Text|| nodo.NodeType ==XmlNodeType.CDATA)
            {
                // Añadimos el nodo a la colecion
                TreeNodeCollection aux = AddNode(nodo, collection);
                // Añade todos los hijos del nodo actual al treeView
                foreach(XmlNode hijos in nodo.ChildNodes)
                {
                    cargandoNodosXML(hijos, aux);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Source + "\n"+ex.Message,"Error al cargar archivos XML",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            mensaje.Text = "";
            string nodo = treeView1.SelectedNode.Text;
            listBox1.Items.Clear();

            foreach (Elemento elemento in ListaElemento)
            {
                if (elemento.nodo == nodo)
                    listBox1.Items.Add(elemento.elemento);


            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error en After_Select ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            mensaje.Text = ex.Message;
        }

    }
    private void BtnBuscarValor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Busqueda())
            MessageBox.Show("El valor ha sido encontrado");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("El valor no ha sido encontrado");

        txtBuscarValor.Text = "";
    }


   private bool Busqueda()
    {

        string nodo = treeView1.SelectedNode.Text;
        foreach (Elemento elemento in ListaElemento)
            if (elemento.nodo == nodo)
                return elemento.elemento == txtBuscarValor.Text;
        return false;
    }
```

}

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y en todo ese codigo, cual es la funcion de busqueda, y sobre que esta buscando? porque no hay nada de eso ahi...

Comment: ok.. agregaste un monton de codigo y una funcion no recursiva que busca.. ahora cual es el problema?

Comment: Que mi función me devuelve el valor del nodo seleccionado y lo compara con el parámetro , pero necesito saber como hacer una función recursiva para que recorra el árbol , no tengo idea como hacerla.

Comment: ok.. agrega el tipo de control que es, porque arriba pusiste un listbox y abajo pareces usar un treeview. Deja solo el codigo que tiene que ver con la pregunta (no todo tu codigo, si no el codigo relevante) y esperemos que alguien te pueda ayudar. Mientras tanto, podes seguir intentandolo.. el treeview tiene nodos, los nodos tiene hijos, y esos hijos tienen hijos, y eso es lo que tenes que hacer recursivo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Var resultado = ListaElemento.any(i => i.campo == "valor");
```

Devuelve true si el elemento existe o false si no existe.

```
Var resultado = ListaElemento.Where(i => i.campo == "valor").List();
```

Devuelve la lista coincidente

```
Var resultado = ListaElemento.any(i => i.campo == "valor").FristorDefault();
```

Devuelve el primer resultado encontrado

Comment: Probable typo: _FirstorDefault_, no _FristorDefault_.